# Tabs in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tabs

I am designing a text editor such that when I select anything in the menu bar , I want the contents of them to be opened in new tab. There are n number of options to select such as Open a file etc

Example :- Say in a notepad I click open and choose some file. I want the contents of the file to be opened in a new tab in the root window

Comment: Can anybody help me with this . I am new to tkinter and I don't have any idea as to how I go about it.

Comment: Have you tried using `ttk.Notebook`?

Comment: Nope I haven't...I read that somewhere else also but using it how many tabs can we create? Do we have to create seperate tab for each of the options in the menubar

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to create a menu that is attached to the window (`tk.Menu`) or tabs like in web browsers (`ttk.Notebook`). For `ttk.Notebook` you can have as many tabs as you want

Comment: Can't we create only one tab such that any time I click on any of the options a new tab appears or do we have to create a seperate tab for each menu option?

Comment: Look at how `tk.Menu` works and some basic examples

Comment: I have created a menu that has options such as file and edit. When I click open and choose a file. I want that file to be opened in a tab in same root window

Comment: That is when I click the menu items I want the contents to be opened in a tab. Similarly when I click some other menu item It should open in another tab and so on

Comment: I suggest You use `ttk.Notebook` and it certainly should be able to dinamically add new tabs

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```py
#=== import all modules===
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

#===== the function====
def open_file():
    # Open filedialogue box to ask for file
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    # If the user clicked cancel stop this function:
    if filename == "":
        return None

    # Try to get a name for the tab.
    try:
        # Try to get the last part of the path. It should be the filename
        title = filename.split("/")[-1]
    except IndexError:
        # If something went wrong use the fill path
        title = filename

    # Create a new text widget
    text_widget = tk.Text(notebook)
    # Create a tab with that text widget
    notebook.add(text_widget, text=title)

    # Open the file, read it and insert the contents in the new text widget
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        text_widget.insert("end", file.read())

# Create the window
root = tk.Tk()
# Create the menu
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Open File", command=open_file)
root.config(menu=menubar)
# Create the tabs widget
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
# Start the tkinter mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Also it would be better if you just used `with open(sd, "r") as file:text_all.insert("end", file.read())` instead of reading the file line by line

Comment: What does the text widget do? And is it mandatory to include it?

Comment: def perm_file():
 text_widget = tk.Text(notebook)
 notebook.add(text_widget)
 notebook.pack(fill = "both")
 with open(gpath,'r') as f:
  data = f.read()
 dom = parseString(data)
 nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')
 l = Listbox(my_frame,height=600,
  width=650,
  bg = "grey",
  activestyle="dotbox",
  font="Arial",
  fg="black")
 co = 0
 for c,node in enumerate(nodes):
  co+=1
  l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
 l.insert(0,f'Number of Permissions : {co}')

 l.pack()

Comment: in the above code i am getting the listbox in the bottom of my window..how do i get it at the top of my window